# Stargate dialing sequence

Tags: stargate

Stargate. One of my favorite things. And so, I have a lot of questions. First, when SG1 dial off world, the chevrons just glow. And when the SGC dial, the glyph ring just rotates. So when there's an off-world activation, will the gate spin?

Comment: You appear to have ended up with [two](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/124130) [separate](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/124154) accounts. You'll probably need to fully register and then [do this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: Which gate?  If they dial differently, do you still expect they have the same reaction to being dialed?

Comment: After you've [merged your accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) if necessary, as suggested above, could you please [edit] your question to clarify a bit? What is it exactly that you want to know?

Answer (score 6):

Off-world activations cause the ring to spin, as seen in this clip from season 1, episode 18 *Solitudes*:

Comment: But only if necessary (see Watergate)